# Save float result number to third digit, no rounding in C

Tags: c, floating-point, rounding, math.h, trigonometry

How to round result to third digit after the third digit.

```
float result = cos(number);
```

Note that I want to save the result up to the third digit, no rounding. And no, I don't want to print it with .3f, I need to save it as new value;

Example:

```
 0.00367 -> 0.003
```

N.B. No extra zeroes after 3 are wanted.

Also, I need to be able to get the 3rd digit. For example if it is 0.0037212, I want to get the 3 and use it as an int in some calculation.

Comment: Detail: as [typical float](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) cannot represent a number like `0.009`, `float x = 0.009;` will result in `x` with the exact value of `0.0089999996125698089599609375`.  In this case, the 3rd digit of the `float` is 8 and not 9.  Is that OK?

Comment: Re, "I don't want to print it."  That's going to be a problem because `float` values don't have decimal digits.  Decimal digits only appear in the printed representation of `float` values.  There is no `float` value that is exactly equal to 0.003.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 0.00367 -> 0.003

A `float` can typically represent about 2<sup>32</sup> different values exactly.  `0.00367` and `0.003` are not in that set.

The closest `float` to `0.00367` is 0.0036700000055134296417236328125
The closest `float` to `0.003__` is 0.0030000000260770320892333984375

> I want to save the result up to the third digit

This goal needs a compromise.  Save the result to a `float` near a multiple of  0.001.

Scaling by 1000.0, truncating and dividing by 1000.0 will work for *most* values.

```
float y1 = truncf(x * 1000.0f) / 1000.0f;
```

The above gives a slightly wrong answer with some values near `x.xxx000...` and `x.xxx999...`.  Using higher precision can solve that.

```
float y2 = (float) (trunc(x * 1000.0) / 1000.0);
```

> I want to get the 3 and use it as an int in some calculation.

Skip the un-scaling part and only keep 1 digit with `fmod()`.

```
int digit = (int) fmod((trunc(x * 1000.0), 10);
digit = abs(digit);
```

---

In the end, I suspect this approach will not completely satisfy OP's unstated "use it as an `int` in some calculation.".  There are many subtitles to FP math, especially when trying to use a *binary* FP, as are most `double`, in some sort of *decimal* way.

Perhaps the following will meet OP's goal, even though it does *some* rounding.:

```
int third_digit = (int) lround(cos(number)*1000.0) % 10;
third_digit = abs(third_digit);
```

Comment: Thank you, the last code gist was what I needed but everything was appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can scale the value up, use `trunc` to truncate toward zero, then scale down:

```
float result = trunc(cos(number) * 1000) / 1000;
```

Note that due to the inexact nature of floating point numbers, the result won't be the exact value.

If you're looking to specifically extract the third decimal digit, you can do that as follows:

```
int digit = (int)(result * 1000) % 10;
```

This will scale the number up so that the digit in question is to the left of the decimal point, then extract that digit.

Comment: I don't want the number to be rounded, the digits must stay the same. For example your way if I do 0.0036 the result becomes 0.004. I want it to be 0.003.

Comment: The `floor` function will do that, at least for positive values.  I've updated to use `trunc` instead which will work for positive and negative values.

Comment: And is there a way to output the result like exactly 0.003, no zeroes after it. Looks okay until now.

Comment: @KarinaK You need to use the `%.3f` format specifier for it to look that way.  The value 0.003 can't be exactly represented an a binary floating point number.  It might actually be 0.003000001 or 0.002999999.

Comment: But can it be stored as a value of 0.003, I mean I need it for calculation of  the third digit, not printing it anywhere.

Comment: @KarinaK As a floating point number, no not exactly.  Perhaps you should update your question regarding what you're *really* trying to accomplish by doing this.

Comment: Updated it, maybe it will be easier to understand.

Comment: @KarinaK See my edit regarding how to get a particular digit.

Comment: @KarinaK, re "I don't want the number to be rounded"  It sounds like you are trying to convert a `float` value to an `int`.  The term of art for that conversion is always "rounding."  Different _kinds_ of rounding are specified as "round up," "round down," "round toward zero," "round to nearest",... but it's always called "rounding."

Comment: @KarinaK, Re, "the digits must stay the same."  Floating point values do not _have_ decimal digits.  The only way you get decimal digits is by printing the number.  If you don't print it, then there are no "digits" that can "stay the same."

Answer (score 1):

You can subtract from the number it's remainder from division by `0.001`:

```
result -= fmod(result, 0.001);
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/VT9Zyx)

**Update:**

The question is updated with very conflicting requirements. If you have an *exact* `0.003` number, there will be *infinite* numbers of zeroes after it, and it is a mathematical property of numbers. OTOH, `float` representation cannot guarantee that every exact number of 3 decimal digits will be represented exactly. To solve this problem you will need to give up on using the `float` type and switch to a some sort of fixed point representation.

Comment: Given that `0.001` cannot be exactly represented by binary floating point I'd be surprised if this always gave the right result. I'd ask for some argument for it.

Comment: @EOF You are right, I didn't want to go into this, given the OP is asking to place the result in `float`, which makes the whole requirement of having the "truncated" value in it somewhat questionable. I would propose to use fixed-point representation at all.

Comment: Look at the question, I updated it. It gives good enough result but i want the number to be saved as 0.00digit not 0.00digit00.

Comment: @EOF Good point, yet I'd expect the "wrong" result is uncommon as `result` is `float` and this answer uses `double` math which will cope with many edge cases.  Still  OP's goal is only partially clear.

Answer (score 0):

Overkill, using sprintf()

```
double /* or float */ val = 0.00385475337;
if (val < 0) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
if (val >= 1) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
char tmp[55];
sprintf(tmp, "%.50f", val);
int third_digit = tmp[4] - '0';
```